# Find handles by process

Tags: windows, process, process-explorer

I am trying to figure out where an undocumented application is storing it's configurations. To find any files it might be using I thought I might be able to use process explorer to view any file handles it might create however I cannot figure out a way to do this. I know I can search for handles by the file opened, is there any way to view all handles opened by a specific process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in process explorer, be sure you have "Show Lower Pane" selected. then select your process in the top pane. All the handles and includes (libraries) for that process are displayed below. scroll through them to see if any point to your config file.

Comment: Hmm well while adams answer is better for the larger picture of what I'm trying to accomplish yours is better in that it directly answers what I was asking.

Comment: For any that find this: this answer works and is a good tip, but Adam's answer is probably more useful here because it'll capture a log of all file/handle access, whereas Process Explorer will only show a current "live" access. If whatever application only pops into the config file and then closes out of it, you may not catch it in the lower pane of Process Explorer. Both tools are great and I use them both all the time, but each has its strengths depending on the scenario. They're great complements to each other.

Comment: @Coldblackice Sure, different tools with similar capabilities are likely to have different characteristics that may help/hinder a specific use-case, and whatever works best for the user is the "right answer". The Op does ask about how to use process explorer specifically though, so this is the correct answer to the question as asked. Adam's answer is 24k gold for anyone who wants to do it the process-monitor way.  Generally, I prefer the heads-up tools, and only dig into logging-based tools like procmon/diskmon when I have a tough nut to crack. its all preference, but the question matters.

Answer (score 4):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (ProcMon.exe) and filter based on process should work for you.

Note: Ctrl+L within Process Explorer will give you a static list of all resources used by process.